# PHP - Get random number by clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i got two php pages, one generating random numbers and another displaying on refresh page.

i want to get current random value by clicking not refreshing.

we could use javascript / ajax / jquery for that please help me any best way

1.php

```
<?php
 include("2.php");

 $getnumber=$_SESSION['randomnumber'];

 ?>

 <button class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" >Get Random Number</button>
```

2.php

```
 <?php
  $rannumber=rand();

   $_SESSION['randomnumber']=$rannumber;
   ?>
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: add `session_start()` on top of your PHP files.

Comment: before asking question. google first..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something with JQuery/Javascript, which won't refresh the page by doing:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
             $("#random").click(function(){
             var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);//Change the 6 to be the number of random numbers you want to generate. So if you want 100 numbers, change to 100
                 $("#number").text(number); 

        });

        });


</script>


            <button class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" id="random" >Get Random Number</button> 
        <div id="number"></div>//<---This is where the random number would be placed
```

I have tested this and it works :)

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5uKe/

Comment: That is pretty much in detail... I'll update so you can add in your code.

Comment: Answer is updated. You will see a live example working. The code I have work :) Just follow the link and you will see it working.

Comment: I hope that helps you. You can basically copy that code and add it to your 1.php file and it will work if you have jquery installed.

Comment: There is no updated session value. This is done without using php. You would have to assign the session value.

Comment: just a general question...i got another php page displaying products from ajax php page... i will use above for getting session value after full ajax run....  on main page. (bring session value from ajax to main page...)

Answer (score 2):

this could be used without any php coding, whenever want something to happen without refreshing the page , javascript is your buddy

```
<div id="randomNum">0</div>
<button onclick="generate()">Randomize</button>
<script>
function generate(){
    var x=document.getElementById("randomNum");
    x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
}
</script>
```

i suggest you take a look over here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Comment: w3schools is one of the worst sites you can recommend. I'd be careful siting it http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: it has some interactive examples over this topic i am not recommanding it for everyday use

Comment: @Blaine choose Fiddle Option : "no wrap - in <head> "in the second dropdown in frameworks & extension